# Clicking a link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little script i made but im wondering if its possible for me to trigger a link on the page with just jQuery.

**JS**

```
var vars = [], hash;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
  {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }

  $('a.more').each(function() {
    var self = this;

    if (vars['deeplink'] == 'true') {
       /* this must trigger the link and that will trigger $(self).click */
    }

    $(self).click(function() {
      var theid = self.href.split('#').pop();
      var row = document.getElementById('info-art' + theid);
      var now = typeof(row.style.display) != 'undefined' ? row.style.display : 'none';
      $('tr.info').each(function() { this.style.display = 'none'; });
      if (now == 'none') {
        row.style.display = $.browser.msie ? 'block' : 'table-row';
      }
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<td><a class="more" href="#8714681006955">[+]</a></td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `jQuery.trigger for this` [jquery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: You're not, by chance, trying to trigger something before it's been bound (like your code above implies) right? The `$(self).click(...)` needs to be assigned to be called with a `.trigger()`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the trigger function simply fire the event? I don't think it'll perform the action (causing the browser to navigate to the clicked link). See the [first comment](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#comment-48277488) in the Support and Contributions section.

Comment: I tried adding $(self).trigger('click'); but it didnt trigger the link. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: trigger does exactly what he's asking for. He never said anything about navigating to a clicked link...

Comment: @Ladineko You probably need to refactor your entire code to use trigger instead of the way you're doing it now.

Comment: @Magicmarkker i just screwed around with the trigger abit and i seem to have gotten it to work... I tryed $(self).trigger('click'); and that didnt work. After placing $('a.more').trigger('click'); it seemed to trigger the link.

Answer (score 7):

```
$( selector ).click()
```

As in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

> When .click() is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click").

Comment: Again, the trigger function only fires the event. It won't perform the native action (causing the browser to navigate to the clicked link). See the [first comment](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#comment-48277488) in the Support and Contributions section.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 His original code isn't navigating anywhere so you're comment is moot

Answer (score 3):

Based on "is it possible for me to trigger a link on the page with just jQuery" I am assuming you want to trigger a native click event (as an alternative to the code you posted). If I understand that correctly, then you may find the answer below helpful.

This is a total copy of [Karl Swedberg](http://www.learningjquery.com/author/karl)'s [answer](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#comment-48277488):

> Using .trigger('click') will not trigger the native click event. To simulate a default click, you can bind a click handler like so:
>
> ```
> $('#someLink').bind('click', function() {
>   window.location.href = this.href;
>   return false;
> });
> ```
>
> where "someLink" is an actual selector of your choice.
>
> You can then trigger that bound click handler if you want, based on some other interaction.
>
> ```
> $('input.mycheckbox').click(function() {
>   if (this.checked) {
>     $('#someLink').trigger('click');
>   }
> });
> ```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#comment-48277488

Be sure to upvote the original author if you find this helpful.